# Need explanation about [java.util.NoSuchElementException: Timeout waiting for idle object]

Tags: java, jdbc, prepared-statement

I get the above exception by calling the bellow method 48 times +/-

```
public ResultSet executePreparedStatement(String preparedStatementQuery, List<?> parameters) throws Exception {

            CachedRowSetImpl rowSet = null;

            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
            Connection connection = connectionPool.getConnection(); // The problem is with this line  

            try {

                connection = connectionPool.getConnection();  
                preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(preparedStatementQuery);

                for (int i=0;i<parameters.size();i++) {
                    preparedStatement.setObject(i+1, parameters.get(i));
                }

                if (SQLHelper.doesQueryReturnsResultSet(preparedStatementQuery))  { 
                    ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
                    rowSet = new CachedRowSetImpl();
                    rowSet.populate(resultSet);
                    resultSet.close();                    

                } else if (SQLHelper.isWriteQuery(preparedStatementQuery)) {
                    preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
                } else {
                    throw new Exception("Query does not return a ResultSet and is not a write query ("+preparedStatementQuery+")");
                }


            } finally {
                   if (preparedStatement!=null) preparedStatement.close();
                   if (connection != null) connectionPool.freeConnection(connection);
            }
            return rowSet;
}
```

The problem is with this line `Connection connection = connectionPool.getConnection();`
If I change it as `Connection connection = null;`- exception doesn't occur.

My question is why? All I'm doing is reassigning the connection in `try` block. Or whenever `ConnectionPool.getConnection()` is called it opens a new connection leaving old one open regardless of that being called on the same object?

**Full stack trace for convenience:**

```
ERROR : 2015-12-08 13:16:46 [com.gotraveltech.hotswap.custom.wings.halliburton.SapHrImportController-] org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot get a connection, pool error Timeout waiting for idle object
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource.getConnection(PoolingDataSource.java:104)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:880)
    at alchimea.utils.sql.DBCP_ConnectionPool.getConnection(DBCP_ConnectionPool.java:36)
    at alchimea.utils.sql.BasicSQLDataSource.executePreparedStatement(BasicSQLDataSource.java:288)
    at com.gotraveltech.hotswap.custom.wings.halliburton.SapHrImportUserDataObjectReconciler.setCompanyTravellerType(SapHrImportUserDataObjectReconciler.java:444)
    at com.gotraveltech.hotswap.custom.wings.halliburton.SapHrImportUserDataObjectReconciler.translateSapHrUserDataObjectToContactPerson(SapHrImportUserDataObjectReconciler.java:410)
    at com.gotraveltech.hotswap.custom.wings.halliburton.SapHrImportUserDataObjectReconciler.updateContactPerson(SapHrImportUserDataObjectReconciler.java:266)
    at com.gotraveltech.hotswap.custom.wings.halliburton.SapHrImportUserDataObjectReconciler.updateSapUserDetails(SapHrImportUserDataObjectReconciler.java:62)
    at com.gotraveltech.hotswap.custom.wings.halliburton.SapHrImportController.processFile(SapHrImportController.java:116)
    at com.gotraveltech.hotswap.custom.wings.halliburton.SapHrImportController.process(SapHrImportController.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at alchimea.utils.hotswap.DynamicObjectLoader.invoke(DynamicObjectLoader.java:338)
    at org.apache.commons.proxy.ProxyFactory$InvokerInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyFactory.java:255)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy118.process(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.jsp.contactList.externalPeople.sapFileImporter.sapFileUploader_jsp._jspService(sapFileUploader_jsp.java:788)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at alchimea.applicationFilter.TmaApplicationFilter.doFilter(TmaApplicationFilter.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at alchimea.aqua.filter.ApplicationLoaderFilter.doFilter(ApplicationLoaderFilter.java:47)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at alchimea.aqua.CharsetFilter.doFilter(CharsetFilter.java:39)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1074)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException: Timeout waiting for idle object
    at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:1134)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource.getConnection(PoolingDataSource.java:96)
    ... 52 more
Send Email
From: it@wings.travel 
To: bugs@gotraveltech.com
Subject: java.util.NoSuchElementException:Timeout waiting for idle object on server: 1
Body:
There has been an Exception on server 1.
Please plan time to fix this.
org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot get a connection, pool error Timeout waiting for idle object
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource.getConnection(PoolingDataSource.java:104)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:880)
    at alchimea.utils.sql.DBCP_ConnectionPool.getConnection(DBCP_ConnectionPool.java:36)
    at alchimea.utils.sql.BasicSQLDataSource.executePreparedStatement(BasicSQLDataSource.java:288)
    at com.gotraveltech.hotswap.custom.wings.halliburton.SapHrImportUserDataObjectReconciler.setCompanyTravellerType(SapHrImportUserDataObjectReconciler.java:444)
    at com.gotraveltech.hotswap.custom.wings.halliburton.SapHrImportUserDataObjectReconciler.translateSapHrUserDataObjectToContactPerson(SapHrImportUserDataObjectReconciler.java:410)
    at com.gotraveltech.hotswap.custom.wings.halliburton.SapHrImportUserDataObjectReconciler.updateContactPerson(SapHrImportUserDataObjectReconciler.java:266)
    at com.gotraveltech.hotswap.custom.wings.halliburton.SapHrImportUserDataObjectReconciler.updateSapUserDetails(SapHrImportUserDataObjectReconciler.java:62)
    at com.gotraveltech.hotswap.custom.wings.halliburton.SapHrImportController.processFile(SapHrImportController.java:116)
    at com.gotraveltech.hotswap.custom.wings.halliburton.SapHrImportController.process(SapHrImportController.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at alchimea.utils.hotswap.DynamicObjectLoader.invoke(DynamicObjectLoader.java:338)
    at org.apache.commons.proxy.ProxyFactory$InvokerInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyFactory.java:255)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy118.process(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.jsp.contactList.externalPeople.sapFileImporter.sapFileUploader_jsp._jspService(sapFileUploader_jsp.java:788)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at alchimea.applicationFilter.TmaApplicationFilter.doFilter(TmaApplicationFilter.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at alchimea.aqua.filter.ApplicationLoaderFilter.doFilter(ApplicationLoaderFilter.java:47)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at alchimea.aqua.CharsetFilter.doFilter(CharsetFilter.java:39)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1074)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException: Timeout waiting for idle object
    at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:1134)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource.getConnection(PoolingDataSource.java:96)
    ... 52 more

java.lang.Exception: [SapHrImportController][processFile]org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException
org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot get a connection, pool error Timeout waiting for idle object
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource.getConnection(PoolingDataSource.java:104)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:880)
    at alchimea.utils.sql.DBCP_ConnectionPool.getConnection(DBCP_ConnectionPool.java:36)
    at alchimea.utils.sql.BasicSQLDataSource.executePreparedStatement(BasicSQLDataSource.java:288)
    at com.gotraveltech.hotswap.custom.wings.halliburton.SapHrImportUserDataObjectReconciler.setCompanyTravellerType(SapHrImportUserDataObjectReconciler.java:444)
    at com.gotraveltech.hotswap.custom.wings.halliburton.SapHrImportUserDataObjectReconciler.translateSapHrUserDataObjectToContactPerson(SapHrImportUserDataObjectReconciler.java:410)
    at com.gotraveltech.hotswap.custom.wings.halliburton.SapHrImportUserDataObjectReconciler.updateContactPerson(SapHrImportUserDataObjectReconciler.java:266)
    at com.gotraveltech.hotswap.custom.wings.halliburton.SapHrImportUserDataObjectReconciler.updateSapUserDetails(SapHrImportUserDataObjectReconciler.java:62)
    at com.gotraveltech.hotswap.custom.wings.halliburton.SapHrImportController.processFile(SapHrImportController.java:116)
    at com.gotraveltech.hotswap.custom.wings.halliburton.SapHrImportController.process(SapHrImportController.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at alchimea.utils.hotswap.DynamicObjectLoader.invoke(DynamicObjectLoader.java:338)
    at org.apache.commons.proxy.ProxyFactory$InvokerInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyFactory.java:255)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy118.process(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.jsp.contactList.externalPeople.sapFileImporter.sapFileUploader_jsp._jspService(sapFileUploader_jsp.java:788)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at alchimea.applicationFilter.TmaApplicationFilter.doFilter(TmaApplicationFilter.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at alchimea.aqua.filter.ApplicationLoaderFilter.doFilter(ApplicationLoaderFilter.java:47)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at alchimea.aqua.CharsetFilter.doFilter(CharsetFilter.java:39)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1074)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException: Timeout waiting for idle object
    at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:1134)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource.getConnection(PoolingDataSource.java:96)
    ... 52 more

    at com.gotraveltech.hotswap.custom.wings.halliburton.SapHrImportController.processFile(SapHrImportController.java:127)
    at com.gotraveltech.hotswap.custom.wings.halliburton.SapHrImportController.process(SapHrImportController.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at alchimea.utils.hotswap.DynamicObjectLoader.invoke(DynamicObjectLoader.java:338)
    at org.apache.commons.proxy.ProxyFactory$InvokerInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyFactory.java:255)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy118.process(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.jsp.contactList.externalPeople.sapFileImporter.sapFileUploader_jsp._jspService(sapFileUploader_jsp.java:788)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at alchimea.applicationFilter.TmaApplicationFilter.doFilter(TmaApplicationFilter.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at alchimea.aqua.filter.ApplicationLoaderFilter.doFilter(ApplicationLoaderFilter.java:47)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at alchimea.aqua.CharsetFilter.doFilter(CharsetFilter.java:39)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.Authen
ticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1074)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are fetching a new DB-connection twice. The first time in the line you have marked as the problematic line yourself. This connection is not freed. Instead, you directly fetch another connection, which is then used and correctly freed in the finally block. However, your first connection retrieved is still reserved on the server. Since the server has a limited amount of connections available, at some point you get the exception that it was not possible to fetch another one.

Fix the problem by just setting the connection variable to `null` when it is first defined (as you suggested yourself).

Comment: Thanks, just wanted proper explanation as I am using the code written by our technical lead and can only change it on his permission.